# How to prefill CkEditor with data using React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, ckeditor, rich-text-editor

I'm creating a blog and I want to give the user the ability to update their post but I'm not sure how to pass the content data from the original post into my rich text editor.

```
import { CKEditor } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react'
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic'

function UpdatePost() {
  const [content, setContent] = useState('')
  const { post_id } = useParams();

 useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPost = async () => {
      const formData = await getPost(post_id);
      setContent(formData.content);
    };
    fetchPost();
  }, [post_id]);

 const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const updated = await updatePost({
      post_id,
      content: content,
    })
  };

 return (
    <div>
        <form
          onSubmit={handleSubmit}
        >
          <h1 class="create-post-header-text">Update Post</h1>
            <CKEditor
              config={{ placeholder: "Content..." }}
              class="ck-editor"
              editor={ClassicEditor}
              onChange={(event, editor) => {
                const data = editor.getData()
                setContent(data)
              }}
            />
          </label>
        </form>
    </div >
  );
}
```

Comment: Hello, have you been able to find a solution? I noticed adding the value={prefilled} prop does not work, and am also curious

Answer (score 0):

It may help, try this ...

```
 <CKEditor
              config={{ placeholder: "Content..." }}
              class="ck-editor"`enter code here`
              editor={ClassicEditor}
           data={<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: content }} />}
              onChange={(event, editor) => {
                const data = editor.getData()
                setContent(data)
              }}
            /

>
```